# Getting undefined (reading 'getLogger') with Msal Provider React TS + Vite

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure-active-directory, msal.js

I'm trying to use the ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial to manage users (sign-in/up).
This is guide I'm following https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/1-call-api/SPA but I think since I'm using TypeScript theres some package or something that I'm doing wrong to not initialize the "intance" correctly because it's not getting the func getLogger.

My AuthConfig is:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 * Licensed under the MIT License.
 */

import { LogLevel } from "@azure/msal-browser";

/**
 * Configuration object to be passed to MSAL instance on creation.
 * For a full list of MSAL.js configuration parameters, visit:
 * https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/configuration.md
 */
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "Enter_the_Application_Id_Here", // This is the ONLY mandatory field that you need to supply.
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/Enter_the_Tenant_Info_Here", // Defaults to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
        redirectUri: "/", // You must register this URI on Azure Portal/App Registration. Defaults to window.location.origin
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "/", // Indicates the page to navigate after logout.
        clientCapabilities: ["CP1"] // this lets the resource owner know that this client is capable of handling claims challenge.
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage", // Configures cache location. "sessionStorage" is more secure, but "localStorage" gives you SSO between tabs.
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
        secureCookies: false
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            /**
             * Below you can configure MSAL.js logs. For more information, visit:
             * https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-logging-js
             */
            loggerCallback: (level: any, message: any, containsPii: any) => {
                if (containsPii) {
                    return;
                }
                switch (level) {
                    case LogLevel.Error:
                        console.error(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Info:
                        console.info(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Verbose:
                        console.debug(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Warning:
                        console.warn(message);
                        return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Add here the endpoints and scopes when obtaining an access token for protected web APIs. For more information, see:
 * https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/resources-and-scopes.md
 */
export const protectedResources = {
    apiTodoList: {
        endpoint: "http://localhost:5000/api/todolist",
        scopes: {
            read: [ "api://Enter_the_Web_Api_Application_Id_Here/Todolist.Read" ],
            write: [ "api://Enter_the_Web_Api_Application_Id_Here/Todolist.ReadWrite" ]
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Scopes you add here will be prompted for user consent during sign-in.
 * By default, MSAL.js will add OIDC scopes (openid, profile, email) to any login request.
 * For more information about OIDC scopes, visit:
 * https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#openid-connect-scopes
 */
export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: [...protectedResources.apiTodoList.scopes.read, ...protectedResources.apiTodoList.scopes.write]
};
```

My Main.ts

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { EventType, PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';

import App from './App'
import './index.css'
import { msalConfig } from './utils/auth/AuthConfig';

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

// Default to using the first account if no account is active on page load
if (!msalInstance.getActiveAccount() && msalInstance.getAllAccounts().length > 0) {
  // Account selection logic is app dependent. Adjust as needed for different use cases.
  msalInstance.setActiveAccount(msalInstance.getAllAccounts()[0]);
}

msalInstance.addEventCallback((event: any) => {
  if (event.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS && event.payload.account) {
      const account = event.payload.account;
      msalInstance.setActiveAccount(account);
  }
});


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App msalInstance={msalInstance}/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

Console output:

```
caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getLogger')
    at MsalProvider.tsx:107:25
    at mountMemo (react-dom.development.js:17225:19)
    at Object.useMemo (react-dom.development.js:17670:16)
    at useMemo (react.development.js:1650:21)
    at MsalProvider (MsalProvider.tsx:106:20)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:13)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <MsalProvider> component:

    at MsalProvider (http://localhost:3011/node_modules/.vite/deps/@azure_msal-react.js?v=f9cbc1be:123:5)
    at App (http://localhost:3011/src/App.tsx?t=1681825109441:19:16)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
react-dom.development.js:26923 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getLogger')
    at MsalProvider.tsx:107:25
    at mountMemo (react-dom.development.js:17225:19)
    at Object.useMemo (react-dom.development.js:17670:16)
    at useMemo (react.development.js:1650:21)
    at MsalProvider (MsalProvider.tsx:106:20)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:13)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:16)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:12)
```

Project Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^2.0.1",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.35.0",
    "@azure/msal-react": "^1.5.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.17",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.18.1",
    "@sentry/react": "^7.45.0",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^7.45.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.3.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "msal": "^1.4.17",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.11.0",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "zxcvbn": "^4.4.2"
  },
```

I've tried googling but not finding the sameish problem with MSAL provider that I can see I'm doing wrong. Followed several interpertations but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

So I do not know what the problem is, but I have found a way to fix it.

Instead of passing msalInstance down to app via props, you can change the line:

```
const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
```

to the following:

```
export const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
```

Then inside app.tsx you import this instead of getting it from props

```
import "./App.css";

import { MsalProvider } from "@azure/msal-react";
import BasePage from "./pages/BasePage";
import { msalInstance } from "./index";

function App() {
  return (
    <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
      <BasePage></BasePage>
    </MsalProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I am following a similar tutorial and I had the same problem.

In my Index.js file I had:

```
<App msalInstance={msalInstance}/>
```

and it was supposed to be:

```
<App instance={msalInstance}/>
```

That resolved my issue and it looks like you did the same thing as me but msalInstance was from another msal tutorial.